# Regexp to split mathematical operators in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a regexp in java that need to split a string to 3 parts (or 4 if the operators are `>=`,`<=`,`!=`), LHS, Operator (can have double values if operator is `>=`,`<=`,`!=`) and value. The supported operators are `>`,`=`,`<`,`>=`,`<=,!=`, and an additional `IN` operator.

The regexp I am using for this is `(?<=[><=!]|in)|(?=[<>=+!]|in)`;

However for a string `value=A+B` it is returning the value in 4 parts.
`value`,`=`,`A`,`+B` . However the expected values in array are `value`,`=`,`A+B`

```
String [] arr =null;
arr = value.split(regexp);
```

How to modify the regexp (I can see if I remove `+` in regexp its returning fine. But need to make sure removing `+` above should not break anything).

Comment: You might want to consider a tiny parser instead.

Comment: A parser in the sense something to split the string based on string manipulation api's?

Comment: Can you provide examples of valid and invalid expressions, and how you want to split them? Are you sure regular expressions are enough for all cases?

Comment: A parser in the sense of a parser; you have a mini-language which *may* be simple enough to handle w/ simplistic string manipulation, but I tend to get pretty nervous any time people start trying to handle expression languages in an ad-hoc manner.

Comment: You could also add a `+` in the look-behind group: `(?<=[><=!+]|in)` . Also I share opinions told previously. It's better to write a parser instead. You're not parsing operators correctness for example.